# Setting custom keys on Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

How can I define my own custom keys on Firebase with Flutter?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently adding a child node by calling [`DatabaseReference.push()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/push.html), which automatically generates a unique ID for that child node.

```
ref.push().set(...)
```

To control the name of the child node, use [`DatabaseReference.child(...)`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/child.html) instead:

```
ref.child('name').set(...)
```